# What to do when there is more than one object in a cell in Yolo v1

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to implement Yolo v1 and I'm kinda stuck with its loss function.

I understand the need of multiple bounding boxes per cell although only one object is detected per cell. Each bounding box can be specialized in some aspect ratios and sizes.

I understand also that when you calculate the loss function, you choose the bounding box that best fits (higher iou) the ground truth object in that cell.

What I don't understand is how do you calculate the loss function when there is actually more than one object in a cell. The loss function doesn't specify it and assumes that one (and only one) object may or may not be in a specific cell.